# Having trouble with persisting React state using localStorage with a SSR (Next.js) app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The app I'm making has customizable settings. I'd like to load default settings, then when a user makes any changes, the custom settings will be stored in localStorage. Now the next time a user comes back, we'll load the setting from their localStorage.

I'm using React context like so...

```
    const SettingsContextProvider = (props: any) => {
        const [settings, setSettings] = useState(getSettings());

        useEffect(() => {
            localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings))
        }, [settings]);

        return (...some jsx...);
    }
```

Then getSettings()...

```
   getSettings() {
       // get from local storage
       if (process.browser) {
           const localSettings = localStorage.getItem('settings');
           if (localSettings) return JSON.parse(localSettings );
       }

       // fall back to default settings
       return "Something else";
   }
```

The issue I'm having is that the server side load (on the node side), we don't have local storage (which is why I check for `process.browser`), so it falls back to default settings. THEN when it gets to the browser, it seems to call `getSettings()` again, in which case we DO have local storage and it loads from there.

That works, **but then I get an error**:

`Text content did not match. Server: "Something else" Client: "Something custom"`

So I understand that the server isn't matching the client and it's upset about it. I get WHY it's happening, but I have NO IDEA how to fix it. Maybe I need to implement reducers or use cookies?

Has anyone come across this?

I'm more than happy to share my full repo code if it'll help.

Comment: What exactly raises this error? Who compares two these values and says `Text content did not match.`?

Comment: It's tough to tell what raises the error. It's in my browser consol as soon as I open the site (error on index.js line 1, so the error doesn't help at all). All I can tell is that initially the server must render the site as it expects, then the client renders it with different data (from local storage) and things break.

Comment: It looks like you have minified your build, and this is the reason why you see error on line 1. You should try with not minified js, so you can track the source of this error. Tracking it is essential to solving of your issue, because without it, it is really hard to tell what part of your code is responsible for this comparison of strings and why is this so important.

Answer (score -3):

I'm fairly comfortable with react but have pretty much NEVER used react hooks in my own code.

However, I feel like I wouldn't put the updating of the localStorage into a `useEffect` function like that (and I could be totally wrong about that).

So, first, I would check that that `useEffect` function is being called when you're expecting it to be.

And then, I would write a function

```
 const updateSettings = (newSettings) => {
      localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(newSettings))
      setSettings(newSettings);
 }
```

And use that `updateSettings` function to pass down to components.

BUT, I could be totally off there, like I said I don't use react hooks and only have a theoretical understanding.

Comment: You're probably right about when to update settings. It doesn't fix the issue, but it's a good point. Thanks!